# Cannot create webview android

Tags: android, webview

I've tried to create a webview in my application. But when I go to find the webview, I had this error

> inconvertible types cannot cast android.view.view webview

this is my code

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
}

}
```

and this is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: check your xml file name .it must be same which you one using ...

Comment: xml file name is activity_main2 !!

Comment: Try with clean and rebuild project.

Comment: thank u i find the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try to re-import Webview and make sure that imported
  import android.webkit.WebView;
- Make sure from using Internet permission in manifest file.

Comment: but how i can open url on the activity not on the browser?

Comment: You can using webView.loadUrl(YOUR URL HERE);

Comment: thank you its working like this 
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl(Url);